# Copying SelectableText in Flutter with MacOS

Tags: macos, flutter

I have the widget:

```
SelectableText("Hello")
```

However, when selecting the word I expected the right-click functionality to be enabled so I could copy the text as well as the ability to `cmd+c`. There is also no sign of the `ToolbarOptions` popping up. And finally, the Edit tab in the menu bar is greyed out:
[image]